# EntityManager injected only once if declared into two different EJBs

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, cdi, java-ee-7

I am on **Weblogic 12c** + **JPA/Hibernate** + **EJB 3**.

I wish to simplify my class model as follow:

```java
public abstract class AbstractEJBBean {

  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPU")
  private EntityManager entityManager;

}

@Local
public interface FirstEJB {
    void someMethod1();
}

@Stateless
public class FirstEJBImpl extends AbstractEJBBean implements FirstEJB {

    @Override
    public void someMethod1() {
        // Here entityManager has been injected.
    }

}

@Local
public interface SecondEJB {
    void someMethod2();
}

@Stateless
public class SecondEJBImpl extends AbstractEJBBean implements SecondEJB {

    @Override
    public void someMethod2() {
        // Here entityManager has NOT been injected!!!
    }

}
```

In such situation, Weblogic starts (no errors logged), the application starts, but: only then entity manager into `FirstEJBImpl` instance have been injected. The one inside `SecondEJBImpl` is `null`!!!

I never seen any like this.

Could somebody tell my why and how to avoid it?

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Show us how do you declare your EJBs.

Comment: I added some details as you requested. Thank you.

Comment: I mean, show us the client code. How you inject the EJBs.

Comment: The client is a Jersey resource into the WAR module which injects them by the EIB annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on my own.

I suppose it is a Weblogic bug, but I am not so sure, but my solution works as expected.

I had to remove the abstract base class and inject the entity manager directly inside each EJB.

```java
@Local
public interface FirstEJB {
    void someMethod1();
}

@Stateless
public class FirstEJBImpl implements FirstEJB {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPU")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void someMethod1() {
        // Here entityManager has been injected.
    }

}

@Local
public interface SecondEJB {
    void someMethod2();
}

@Stateless
public class SecondEJBImpl implements SecondEJB {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPU")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void someMethod2() {
        // Here entityManager has been injected too! :)
    }

}
```